# react dnd DropTarget not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I want to be able to drag and drop between two list of cards.

Based on the simple [sortable example](http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/examples-sortable-simple.html) i've succeed to build two lists with cards and drag and drop between them.

For some reason when one of the lists is completely empty i can't drop cards in it.

This snippet demonstrate my problem:

```js
const ItemTypes = {
    CARD: 'card'
};

let cardSource = {
    beginDrag: function (props, monitor, component) {
        // Return the data describing the dragged item
        return {
            card: props.card,
            originalList: props.cardList,
            originalIndex: props.findCard(props.card).index,
            targetList: props.cardList // at first target is same as original
        }
    },

    endDrag: function (props, monitor, component) {
        let item = monitor.getItem();
        let dropResult = monitor.getDropResult();
        if (!monitor.didDrop()) {
            props.moveCard(item.card, item.originalIndex);
            if (item.targetList !== item.originalList) {
                item.targetList.removeCard(item.card);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
};

let cardTarget = {
    canDrop: function (props, monitor) {
        return true;
    },

    hover: function (props, monitor) {
        let item = monitor.getItem();

        if (item.targetList !== props.cardList) {
            item.targetList.removeCard(item.card);
            item.targetList = props.cardList;
        }

        if (item.card.id !== props.card.id) {
            let card = props.findCard(props.card);
            props.moveCard(item.card, card.index);
        }
    },

    drop: function (props, monitor, component) {
        return monitor.getItem();
    }
};


class CardElement extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let isDragging = this.props.isDragging;
        let connectDragSource = this.props.connectDragSource;
        let connectDropTarget = this.props.connectDropTarget;
        let opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1; // Not working as expected

        let elm = <div className="card-item" style={{ opacity: opacity }}> Name: { this.props.card.name } id { this.props.card.id } </div>;
        return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(elm));
    }
}

CardElement.propTypes = {
    connectDragSource: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    connectDropTarget: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isDragging: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    card: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    cardList: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    moveCard: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    findCard: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

let cardDropTarget = ReactDnD.DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, function (connect, monitor) {
    return {
        connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()
    }
})(CardElement);

let Card = ReactDnD.DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, function (connect, monitor) {
    return {
        connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    };
})(cardDropTarget);

let cardListTarget = {
    drop: function (props, monitor, component) { 
      // when the list empty the cards not dropping here
    },
    canDrop: function () {
        return true;
    }
};

class ListElement extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cards: this.props.cards
        };
    }

    moveCard(card, atIndex) {
        let found = this.findCard(card);
        let cards = this.state.cards;

        if (found.card) {
            cards.splice(found.index, 1);
            cards.splice(atIndex, 0, found.card);
        } else {
            cards.splice(atIndex, 0, card);
        }
        this.setState({ cards: cards });
    }

    removeCard(card) {
        let found = this.findCard(card);
        let cards = this.state.cards;
        if (found.card) {
            cards.splice(found.index, 1);
        } else {
            // console.log('Can\'t remove card ' + card.id + ' - can\'t find it');
        }
        this.setState({ cards: cards });
    }

    findCard(card) {
        let index = this.state.cards.indexOf(card);
        if (index >= 0) {
            // console.log('found: card: ' + card + ' with id ' + card.id);
        } else {
            // console.log('didn\'t find card');
            card = null;
        }
        return {
            card: card,
            index: index
        };
    }

    render() {
        let connectDropTarget = this.props.connectDropTarget;

        let cardList = this.state.cards.map(card => {
            return <Card key={ card.id }
                card={ card }
                cardList={ this }
                moveCard={ this.moveCard.bind(this) }
                findCard={ this.findCard.bind(this) }
                />
        });

        return connectDropTarget(<div className="col"> {cardList} </div>);
    }
}

let List = ReactDnD.DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardListTarget, (connect, monitor) => {
    return {
        connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()
    }
})(ListElement);

class AppElement extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let listA = [
            { name: 'Harry', id: 1 },
            { name: 'Jimmy', id: 2 },
            { name: 'Jane', id: 3 },
            { name: 'Adam', id: 4 },
            { name: 'Judith', id: 5 }
        ]
        let listB = [
            { name: 'Edward', id: 6 },
            { name: 'Ronald', id: 7 },
            { name: 'Irene', id: 8 },
            { name: 'Patrick', id: 9 },
            { name: 'Dorothy', id: 10 }
        ]
        this.state = {
            cards: [listA, listB]
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <div id="warper">
            <List cards={ this.state.cards[0]} />
            <List cards={ this.state.cards[1]} />
        </div>;
    }
}
let App = ReactDnD.DragDropContext(ReactDnDHTML5Backend)(AppElement);

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
#warper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.col {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 5px 31px 0px 0px;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 9px;
}
.card-item {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dnd-html5-backend@2.1.2/dist/ReactDnDHTML5Backend.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dnd@2.1.4/dist/ReactDnD.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

i can't figure out way when list is empty it's not let me drop cards into it.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: there are no code errors - it's working, but not in the way i want to. i want to be able dropping cards in empty list

Comment: I noticed an issue. The cards in state should be immutable. Copy the cards into a new array using slice before splicing.

Comment: i agree it is an issue, but it's not the problem. The problem is in cardListTarget (as far as i understand). The ListElement should be dropTarget, but for some reason it's not

Answer (score 0):

Decide where you want to handle drop.
Now you are handling adding card logic on hover of separate cards.
Drag and drop does not work with not empty list also, if you drop it not on a item, but on the empty space under the items.